# Convert Zero Length String To Blank In Microsoft Access

Tags: string, ms-access, zero

I have zero length strings in an excel file that I am importing into access.  I would like to convert these zero length strings into a completely blank cell.  I would like to do this completely in Access.  Any suggestions?

I have tried using a iif and format within access but I can't change the format.  My problem is the cell needs to either be blank or formatted as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean exactly with "completely blank cell" and as you didn't provide any detail, it's hard to tell.

However, by making sure that the property "Allow Zero Length" for the Data Type of the Field in the Access table is set to false (for a Text field, of course) then these values should be converted to a Null value when imported and should appear as completetly blank.

You could also make an update query after the importation to convert any zero length strings to a Null value; something like:

```
Update Table1 Set Field1 = Null Where Field1 = ""
```

Comment: Well my problem is that I have an excel spreadsheet that I copy and paste data into and then run a number of if statements.  Part of the if statement puts a "" into the cell if the condition is false.  So in my excel file I have a column of data that contains numbers and "".  When I link this excel file to access, access is not able to recognize the format of this column because it is picking up the numbers and "" which are read as text.  So I would like to some how convert the "" so that I can change the whole field to a number format.

Comment: The easiest way of doing this would be to change the type of the field from a Number to a Text in Access; possibly as a temporary used only for the importation.  A better solution would be to use an appropriate query expression that will do the conversion on the fly; for example with an IIF() expression and some casting.  However, you cannot do that with a simple Copy and Paste; you will have to write some code in VBA in order to make the importation from Excell to Access.  There are numerous examples on the web on how to query Excell from Access using VBA.  Any of these should be appropriate.